# Spring data jpa repository retrieve multiple counts

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have the following domain entities:
*Conversation*, which has a list of *Message*s, each of them has a set **newFor** *Participant*s. For whom the message in a list has not been read yet.

I'm struggling with writing a repository interface method (or query) to retrieve a map of conversations having a number of unread messages for this participant.

Atm I use the following to retrieve just a list of conversations:

```
@Query("SELECT c from Conversation c JOIN c.participants p WHERE :participant IN p")
List<Conversation> findByParticipantsIn(Participant participant, Pageable pageable);
```

But I need to somehow update the query to be able to include the count of nested unread messages. Something like that:

```
@Query("SELECT c, count(..my problem is here..) from Conversation c LEFT JOIN c.participants p WHERE :participant IN p ")
List<Object[]> findByParticipantsIn(Participant participant, Pageable pageable);
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to put joins to *count()* or what else could I use here?

**UPD**

Entity fragments exposing the relationships:

```
public class Conversation {
...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Participant> participants = new LinkedHashSet<>();
...
}

public class Message {
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Participant> newFor = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

**Participant** is not aware of **Message** and **Conversation** existence.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested unread messages"?

Comment: Conversation has a collection of messages. Every message has a collection of participants who hasn't read this message yet.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of `Conversation`, `Message` and `Participant` entities? (to see the relationships)

Comment: @EugenCovaci I've added the code fragments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `Conversation` you should have `participants` also.

Comment: @EugenCovaci oh indeed. Corrected.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with JPA.

Comment: What approach would you suggest then? Is there any chance to use native queries here?

Comment: Native query looks doable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could accomplish the goal of retrieving the data invoking a single repository method this way:

```
@Query("SELECT c, (SELECT COUNT(m) FROM Message m WHERE m.conversation = c AND :participant MEMBER OF m.newFor) " +
        "FROM Conversation c " +
        "WHERE :participant MEMBER OF c.participants " +
        "GROUP BY c, c.lastMessage.createdDate " +
        "ORDER BY c.lastMessage.createdDate DESC")
List<Object[]> findConversationsPerParticipant(Participant participant, Pageable pageable);
```

This query retrieves conversations for the given `participant` plus a count of unread messages in accordance with the described above data model.

Not sure if this approach is efficient enough but I believe that it might work faster than 2 separate calls to a remote DB.